# ¿cómo leer consulta de bd?

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy utilizando **laravel** y hago al siguiente consulta:

```
$cantidadDeposito  = DB::select('SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM `finanzas` WHERE miembro = ?', [$idNombre]);
print_r ($cantidadDeposito);
```

Lo cual me da como resultado:

```
stdClass Object ( [SUM(cantidad)] => 750 )
```

¿cómo puedo leer sólo el número?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses un alias en tu consulta asi:

```
$cantidadDeposito  = DB::select('SELECT SUM(cantidad) 
AS total FROM `finanzas` WHERE miembro = ?', [$idNombre]);
```

y luego para imprimirlo:

```
echo $cantidadDeposito->total;
```

Comment: gracias Alan, salduos cordiales.